# excel VBA, checking which week a list of dates fall into

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty inexperienced VBA user here...

I have a list of dates in a range of fixed length and a list of week start-dates in another fixed range.
I want to check which week each of the dates ends up in.

I made a start with the code but am now running into problems trying to nest two for..each loops.
I think I am getting my end if and next statements placed incorrectly.
I get the error 'end if without block if'.
Im also wondering, if it is even necessary to use two for..each loops to do this.

I have just put the print yes and no lines in to check if what im trying to do works - if it does ill go on to replace the print lines with the next stages of code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
Dim due As Range
Dim dueDate As Date
Dim datecell As Range
Dim cashflow As Range
Dim cashcell As Range
Dim startweek As Date
Dim endweek As Date

Set due = Range("H21:H36")
Set cashflow = Range("N19:AT19")

    For Each cashcell In cashflow
        If IsDate(cashcell.Value) Then
            startweek = cashcell.Value
            endweek = cashcell.Offset(0, 2).Value

                For Each datecell In due

                If datecell >= startweek And datecell < endweek Then

                    Debug.Print "YES"
                    Else
                    Debug.Print "NO"
        End If
        End If
    Next datecell
    Next cashcell

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: check out this [smart indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to fix your indentation. Makes the logical flow a lot easier to follow if you indent properly.

Comment: Are you intending to check every cell in the ranges or just a single column?

Comment: In general, it is helpful for others if you provide error message you are getting

Comment: hi @Nathan_Sav, yes, i want to check every cell in the range 'due' to see between which dates from the range 'cashflow' they land

Comment: hi @BigBen thanks for the tip, i though my indentation was probably all over the place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the liberty of matching the indents of your `If` and `For` loop starts and end:

```
Dim due As Range
Dim dueDate As Date
Dim datecell As Range
Dim cashflow As Range
Dim cashcell As Range
Dim startweek As Date
Dim endweek As Date

Set due = Range("H21:H36")
Set cashflow = Range("N19:AT19")

    For Each cashcell In cashflow
        If IsDate(cashcell.Value) Then
            startweek = cashcell.Value
            endweek = cashcell.Offset(0, 2).Value

                For Each datecell In due

                    If datecell >= startweek And datecell < endweek Then
                        Debug.Print "YES"
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "NO"
                    End If
        End If    ' <-- this If statement starts OUTSIDE the for loop
               Next datecell ' <-- This For loop starts INSIDE the If IsDate...
    Next cashcell

End Sub
```

Your issue is you cannot end your `If IsDate...` clause before you end your `For Each datecell...` clause.  Switch the two rows so that your `Next datecell` statement is run before your `End If` and your code should execute